# How to do custom routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I can't use simple routing like in .NET Core 2.2 in .NET Core 3.1.

What is the routing last change in .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: The change was from 2.2 to 3.0, as documented in [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?#routing-startup-code). For MVC the new endpoint routing can be [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?#use-mvc-without-endpoint-routing) by setting `services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);`

Answer (score 17):

In .NET 3 you should use **Endpoint** instead of **Routing**

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
//other middleware

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapHub<MyChatHub>();
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<MyCalculatorService>();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Next to Endpoint's you can also use attribute routing, or combine the two.

```
[Route("my/")]
public class MyController : Controller

[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("")] //prefer this if we asked for this action
[Route("index", Order = 1)]
[Route("default.aspx", Order = 100)] // legacy might as well get an order of 100
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIndex()
{
}
```

With the above attribute for the controller, you do not need to specify MapControllerRoute for this controller. The action has three routes in this example.